# How to find the next sequence of a particular event based on timestamp in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

I have 2 tables:- `views_tbl` table (page views) and `play_tbl` table (which records how long a customer has play a particular video). The `nowPlaying` page_type from `views_tbl` will have the same timestamp in `play_tbl`. Hence timestamps are the only column that can be used to join these 2 tables.

```
play_ts = event_ts when page_type = 'nowPlaying';
```

I am trying to find the count of `browseFind` that lead to a successful playback event (`nowPlaying` page_type from `views_tbl`),based on the following criteria.

If a `browseFind` is followed by `browseSearch`, then that case would be ignored, (after a `browseFind` there should be no `browseSearch` event, but there can be others).

**E.g.** For the first `browseFind` occurred at `2021-01-07 00:36:57.321`, we have an immediate `browseSearch`, hence this would be ignored.
For the next occurrence of `browseFind` at `2021-01-07 11:17:27.286`, there is no immediate browseSearch between the following `nowPlaying` page_type, hence this will be considered in the count. Also the `duration_seconds` from `play_tbl`
Should be greater than 30 for it to be accounted. If the duration is less than 30 sec, then I ignore the case.

I tried to do this by combining both the tables into a Union, but LEAD and LAG did not give me any result.

```
select
tbl_name,
play_ts,
ctrl_nm,
genre,
album_id,
song_id,
duration_seconds
 FROM play_tbl
union
select tbl_name, event_ts, page_type, NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL from views_tbl  ;
```

And then Tried to use `LEAD` and `LAG`. I am using Redshift as my database. I could not get the correct combination of rows.

**Output:** Count of `browseFind` that led to `nowPlaying` with duration greater than 30 sec and no `browseSearch` Event in between them.

Any help would be appreciated. I don't know how to write sql that can go step by step or row after row finding the correct criteria.

**Tables DDL:**

```
create table play_tbl (tbl_name varchar(10), play_ts timestamp, ctrl_nm varchar(10), genre varchar(100), album_id varchar(50), song_id varchar(50), duration_seconds int);

insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 03:17:51.474',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99FPD1MCJ',  212);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:17:37.228',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99K2XSNY3',  175);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:48:19.136', 'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99328YJBW',  155);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:49:51.419',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B999PR4XRS',  48);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:50:26.264',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99C98DB5T',  89);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:52:56.433',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99L88RQZS',  12);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 19:14:53.865',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99GWTZZ3H',  23);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 19:40:46.806',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99NCVV16G',  185);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 19:48:47.708',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99BVYG1S6',  48);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 21:30:03.102',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99C9KDQW6',  69);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 11:17:33.655',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99FPH4GD1',  232);
insert into play_tbl values ('play',  '2021-01-07 21:30:05.931',  'umse',  'browseGema',  'B089999999',  'B99GFBC4V5',   2);



create table views_tbl (tbl_name varchar(10), event_ts timestamp, page_type varchar(150));

insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 00:36:55.33','detail-userPlaylist');       
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 00:36:52.328','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 00:36:57.321','browseFind');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 00:37:03.871','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 03:17:42.541','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 03:17:45.78','detail-userPlaylist');      
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 03:17:51.474','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:25.38','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:27.286','browseFind');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:29.048','browseGema');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:32.342','browseGema');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:31.363','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:34.221','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:17:37.228','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:04.055','browseGema');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:04.796','browseFind');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:05.359','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:08.778','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:19.136','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:48:12.066','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:49:51.419','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:50:12.778','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:50:17.936','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:50:26.264','nowPlaying');               
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:21.502','browseFind');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:26.201','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:27.375','browseHome');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:36.111','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:42.604','browseHome');      
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:41.909','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:45.771','browseFind');               
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:53.719','detail-album');      
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:52:56.433','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:59:38.747','browseSearch');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:59:39.718','browseFind');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:59:41.481','browseHome');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:59:43.998','detail-playlist');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 11:59:47.427','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 12:00:58.284','browseHome');      
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 12:24:15.929','browseHome');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 18:34:15.191','browseHome');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:14:47.426','browseHome');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:14:50.187','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:14:52.098','detail-userPlaylist');     
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:14:53.865','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:40:45.267','detail-userPlaylist');     
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:40:43.486','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:40:46.806','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:48:42.942','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:48:46.362','detail-userPlaylists');    
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 19:48:47.708','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:29:54.488','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:29:56.973','activity-feed');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:30:01.206','detail-userPlaylist');     
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:29:59.795','cloudLibrary-playlists');   
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:30:03.102','nowPlaying');        
insert into views_tbl values ('view',  '2021-01-07 21:30:05.931','nowPlaying');
```

Comment: Redshift or MySQL? those are two very different databases.

Comment: What's the desired result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The database is Redshift, but I am able to copy the data over to MySQL if there is a need to use functions available only in MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: @Strawberry: The desired output is 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issues correctly (the answer is 4 for your data) then I think the issue is how to treat browseSearch and browseFind as special cases in the view events.  In the below SQL I did this with a DECODE (use CASE if you prefer) and added the IGNORE NULLS to the LAG().  I left extra columns in the sub-selects in case you want to run each level by itself to get comfortable with what is happening.  If not completely correct it should give you the hints you need to adjust to your exact desires.

```
SELECT COUNT(DECODE(prev_browse,'browseFind',duration_seconds,NULL)) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT event_ts,
             LAG(browse_type IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY event_ts) AS prev_browse,
             page_type,
             duration_seconds
      FROM (SELECT event_ts,
                   page_type,
                   DECODE(page_type IN ('browseFind', 'browseSearch'),
                          TRUE, page_type,
                          NULL
                   ) AS browse_type,
                   duration_seconds
            FROM views_tbl v
              LEFT JOIN play_tbl p
                     ON v.event_ts = p.play_ts
                    AND v.page_type = 'nowPlaying'
            WHERE page_type IN ('nowPlaying','browseFind','browseSearch')
            AND   (p.duration_seconds >= 30 OR p.duration_seconds IS NULL)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your hints, the correct answer should be 2. I think I can modify the query to suit the conditions.

Comment: Good to hear.  All the best.